# Laptop semi-consistently DCs from internet despite ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, ethernet

Laptop System information:

1. **CPU:** I7-2670QM
2. **GPU:** Geforce GT 630M
3. **Ram:** 8gb
4. **Ethernet adapter:** Broadcom Netlink Gigabyte Ethernet
5. **Modem/Router:** NETGEAR Nighthawk Cable Modem WiFi Router Combo C7000|AC-1900

**Problem I'm Having:** I'm trying to set up a dedicated server for the game Valheim on my old laptop. The problem I'm having is that my laptop appears to lose connection to the internet frequently and randomly. It's happened between 2 and 40 minutes (Last night it was able to sustain a connect for several hours). After the connection is lost, it will not re-establish on its own. I've tried waiting for up to 20-30 minutes to see if the computer would find the connection again and it does not. I have to run the windows network trouble shooter which resets the ethernet adapter and then the internet comes back. When the trouble shooter is finished, generally I get two different errors. the first is that the ethernet adapter had to be reset, which is alway marked as "resolved." Second, I get an error about not being able to reach the internet with a small caution sign. Recently I've sometimes been getting a differnt error stating the default gateway is not available, which is marked as "resolved" when it comes up. the inability to connect to the internet is ONLY affecting my laptop.

**What I've Attempted so far:**

1. CMD DNS Release -> renew -> reset
2. Turned off "power down this device to save power." (This appears to have helped, but heavy internet use still sort of brings it down)
3. Couple of different netsh commands suggested around google.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting timeout and lifetime, https://ansaurus.com/question/2748706-connection-timeout-and-connection-lifetime ?

Comment: I actually fixed my issues with the server specifically, modified question to reflect that. Now I just have the problem with the internet cutting out and needing a ethernet adapter reset randomly

Comment: There are a lot of complaints about this issue with your adapter. Some people in 2015 claimed to have success with driver version 12.4.0.3 dated 10/16/2009. I see your GPU is dated around 2012

Comment: If, alas, as @Yorik states, the Ethernet adapter and/or its drivers at fault, you might try a USB-Ethernet adapter, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb+ethernet+adapter , if it's worth the time and expense to try.